# How to Tune Virtualmin Website for High Traffic? (Alt: How to defend against DoS?)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, cloudflare, virtualmin

I have a website running on PHP-FPM/Nginx/MariaDB, hosted through Virtualmin on an 8GB RAM, 4 core Xeon 3.1ghz CPU, hidden behind Cloudflare.

Recently, we've had a number of simple DoS attacks, a single person running a script like this on their browser console:

```
setInterval(function() { fetch("/") }, 1)
```

Is capable of bringing the website down with ease. I have tried fine-tuning the PHP-FPM configuration for high traffic, no dope, I have tried increasing the RAM for MariaDB, also no luck.

This is my PHP-FPM config:

```
listen.mode = 0660
pm = static
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 16
pm.min_spare_servers = 8
pm.max_spare_servers = 16
php_value[memory_limit] = 128M
php_value[max_execution_time] = 300
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Isn't possible that a single person can bring a whole website down with a simple Javascript command.

Comment: So what your server *is doing* at that moment? How fast it generates a requested page? In general, if you can't generate pages quickly enough, you can't sustain DoS (i.e. no tuning would ever help). Also, virtualmin and the like is *an offtopic* here and it is generally doesn't matter for the problem you are facing, how exactly you manage the server; just remove that unneccessary information (of course, if the problematic application is not virtualmin itself — then the answer would be "don't use it, problem solved").

Comment: The server in this case would be a web app with a large database, akin to a forum.

Comment: Do profiling and optimization of your app. Nothing else could ever help against big rush of absolutely legitimate requests to the title page `GET / HTTP/1.1`. What does the server really do when generating the reply to such a request (this is what I asked you in the first place and you ignored the question)? Does it access the database? May be, indexing of the database or optimization of queries could help? Does it do some processing in PHP? Probably, use less processing? Does it depend on some third party service? Maybe, make that dependency asynchronous?

Comment: If it is a single person then just block his IP. Add request limits per IP if he is changing his connections. Add a small cache for the front page, even a few seconds should help.

Comment: I think people believe just adding a cloudflare automatically caches everything. No, it isn't. To cache the dynamic content **your application must provide hints** to cloudflare for it to know what to cache and for how long, in the form form of cache-control, etag and other caching-related HTTP response headers. For static content, your web server is likely providing that automatically and cloudflare is currently only caches that.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe some iptables rules help

```
### 1: Drop invalid packets ###
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

### 2: Drop TCP packets that are new and are not SYN ###
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP

### 3: Drop SYN packets with suspicious MSS value ###
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcpmss ! --mss 536:65535 -j DROP

### 4: Block packets with bogus TCP flags ###
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,PSH PSH -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL SYN,RST,ACK,FIN,URG -j DROP

### 5: Block spoofed packets ###
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 224.0.0.0/3 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 169.254.0.0/16 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j DROP

### 6: Drop ICMP (you usually don't need this protocol) ###
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p icmp -j DROP

### 7: Drop fragments in all chains ###
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -f -j DROP

### 8: Limit connections per source IP ###
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 111 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

### 9: Limit RST packets ###
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP

### 10: Limit new TCP connections per second per source IP ###
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 60/s --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP

### 11: Use SYNPROXY on all ports (disables connection limiting rule) ###
#/sbin/iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j CT --notrack
#/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,UNTRACKED -j SYNPROXY --sack-perm --timestamp --wscale 7 --mss 1460
#/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

### SSH brute-force protection ###
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j DROP

### Protection against port scanning ###
/sbin/iptables -N port-scanning
/sbin/iptables -A port-scanning -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 2 -j RETURN
/sbin/iptables -A port-scanning -j DROP
```

---

And use this in php fpm

```
; Set appropriate permissions for Unix sockets
listen.mode = 0660

; Use a dynamic process manager
pm = dynamic

; Adjust the maximum number of child processes
pm.max_children = 50

; Start with a moderate number of servers
pm.start_servers = 10

; Keep a few spare servers to handle increased load
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 15

; Set a reasonable memory limit for PHP processes
php_value[memory_limit] = 256M

; Increase the maximum execution time for PHP scripts
php_value[max_execution_time] = 600
```

Comment: Again, *it is behind cloudflare*, all the fraffic it sees is likely coming only from cloudflare (else it's useless), which of course doesn't play games at the TCP/IP level with its own customers.

Comment: This is a second stage filter with rate limiting if it goes through cloudflare

Comment: I made an edit to include also some fpm tweaks

Comment: IPTables wouldn't really help, all the traffic goes through Cloudflare and nobody but me has access to the origin server's IP.

Comment: @Turdie this "second stage filter" with IPtables **will make things worse**. Instead of just processing the requests, the server now additionally needs to process firewall rules. If rate limiting gets into play, it will ensure that under even slightest overlimit legitimate users will get backend timeout errors from cloudflare — which means, the attacker achieved their goal of denying the service, even not consuming all the allocated server resources. // Please stop suggesting crappy solutions; **no provably helpful solution is possible without analysis** which we are yet to see.

Comment: Adding `max_execution_time` of 10 minutes is a very smart anti-DoS measurement. /sarcasm

Answer (score -2):

Maybe IDPS using suricata. Suricata does deep inspection in the packet and can integrate with cf

```
#!/bin/bash

# Cloudflare API credentials
CF_API_KEY="your_api_key"
CF_API_EMAIL="your_email@example.com"
CF_ZONE_ID="your_zone_id"

# Suricata log path
SURICATA_LOG_PATH="/var/log/suricata/eve.json"

# Install Suricata
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install suricata -y

# Enable Suricata service
sudo systemctl enable suricata
sudo systemctl start suricata

# Backup the original Suricata configuration file
sudo cp /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml.bak

# Modify Suricata configuration for basic setup
sudo sed -i 's|#default-rule-path: /etc/suricata/rules|default-rule-path: /etc/suricata/rules|' /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml
sudo sed -i 's|#rule-files:|rule-files:|' /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml
sudo sed -i 's|#  - suricata.rules|  - suricata.rules|' /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml

# Download a basic set of Suricata rules
sudo suricata-update enable-source et/open
sudo suricata-update

# Restart Suricata to apply changes
sudo systemctl restart suricata

# Configure Logpush for Suricata logs with Cloudflare
echo "cloudflare:
  token: $CF_API_KEY
  email: $CF_API_EMAIL
  zone: $CF_ZONE_ID
  dataset: suricata" | sudo tee -a /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml

# Restart Suricata to apply Logpush configuration
sudo systemctl restart suricata

echo "Suricata installed, configured, and integrated with Cloudflare DDoS prevention."
```

And then you can configure some IDPS rules

```
#!/bin/bash

# Cloudflare API credentials
CF_API_KEY="your_api_key"
CF_API_EMAIL="your_email@example.com"
CF_ZONE_ID="your_zone_id"

# Path to Suricata custom rules directory
CUSTOM_RULES_DIR="/etc/suricata/rules/custom"

# Create custom rules directory if it doesn't exist
sudo mkdir -p "$CUSTOM_RULES_DIR"

# Create a custom rule file (e.g., custom-ddos.rules)
sudo tee "$CUSTOM_RULES_DIR/custom-ddos.rules" > /dev/null <<'EOF'
# Custom rule to detect and log potential DDoS-like behavior and notify Cloudflare
alert ip any any -> any any (msg:"Potential DDoS-like Behavior"; \
                          threshold: type limit, track by_src, seconds 60, count 100, \
                          sid:1000001; \
                          flowbits: set,ddos_detected; \
                          flowbits: set,cf_notify;)

alert ip any any -> any any (msg:"DDoS Detection: Log and Notify Cloudflare"; \
                          flowbits: isset,ddos_detected; \
                          flowbits: isset,cf_notify; \
                          metadata: cloudflare_rule_id 123456; \
                          flowbits: unset,cf_notify; \
                          flowbits: unset,ddos_detected; \
                          flowbits: set,cf_logged; \
                          sid:1000002;)
EOF

# Restart Suricata to apply the new rule
sudo systemctl restart suricata

echo "Custom DDoS prevention rule added."

# Logpush endpoint
LOGPUSH_ENDPOINT="https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$CF_ZONE_ID/logpush/jobs"

# Log to Cloudflare when DDoS-like behavior is detected
tail -n0 -F /var/log/suricata/eve.json | while read -r line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -q "flowbits: set,cf_logged"; then
        continue
    fi

    if echo "$line" | grep -q "flowbits: set,ddos_detected"; then
        # Log to Cloudflare using Logpush API
        curl -X POST "$LOGPUSH_ENDPOINT" \
            -H "X-Auth-Key: $CF_API_KEY" \
            -H "X-Auth-Email: $CF_API_EMAIL" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
            --data-raw "{\"fields\": {\"message\": \"$line\"}}"

        # Set flowbit to indicate that the log has been sent to Cloudflare
        sudo echo "$line" | suricatasc -c "flowbit-set,cf_logged"
    fi
done
```

You can also include a rule for http traffic

```
alert tcp any any -> $HOME_NET 80 (msg: "Possible DDoS attack"; flags: S; flow: stateless; threshold: type both, track by_dst, count 200, seconds 1; sid:1000001; rev:1; \
    flowbits: set,ddos_detected; flowbits: set,cf_notify; flowbits: set,drop_traffic;)
```